# overriding functions in c++

Tags: c++, overriding, member-hiding

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
virtual void some_func(int f1)
{
cout <<"Base is called: value is : " << f1 <<endl;
}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
virtual void some_func(float f1)
{
cout <<"Derived is called : value is : " << f1 <<endl;
}
};


int main()
{
int g =12;
float f1 = 23.5F;

Base *b2 = new Derived();
b2->some_func(g);
b2->some_func(f1);
return 0;

}
```

Output is :

```
Base is called: value is : 12
Base is called: value is : 23
```

Why is the second call `b2->some_func(f1)` calling `Base` class's function,even though there is a version with float as argument available in `Derived` class?

Comment: There is a new C++11 keyword `override`.  Put it at the end of the method signature `some_func` in `Derived` and the error message will help.

Comment: NEVER forget to delete heap pointers.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's not actually overridden, since its arguments don't have the same type.
2. Since it's not overridden, your pointer to `Base` only knows the `int` method, so it performs a narrowing conversion (there should be a warning) and calls `Base::some_func(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will "function hiding" come into picture here ? I remember function hiding is about having the same function name in the derived class irrespective of the signature. I tried doing Derived d; d.some_func(g); It compiles.

Answer (score 2):

you have confused overloading with overriding , 
For overriding , the signature of the function must remain same.
please check the c++ documentation again .. hope this is helpful

Comment: +1: Though you didn't said it clearly, I understand when I realize it's overloading.

Comment: At first i thought it had to do with the way he instantiated his class (using b2) . So if i understood correctly (i am not rknowledgeable in c++) he is overriding the class Base but overloading the function some_func ??? If this is correct, i found examples on the net on how to override a class ( rectangle -> box ...), but how can we override a function

Comment: you override a class by overriding functions in that class with same signature , if you don't override functions in derived class , the derived class will not provide any different behavior except define a new type.